# partially order

Tags: functions, order-theory

$( A,\le)$ and $(A',\le')$ are partially ordered sets. A map $\phi : A \to A'$ is called *order preserving*  from $(A, \le)$ to $(A', \le')$ if for all  $x, y \in A : x \le y \implies \phi(x) \le'   \phi(y)$

For example:

For $(P(\{1,2\}), \subseteq)$ and $(\mathbb{N}, \le)$ is the map
$\phi : P(\{1,2\}) \to \mathbb{N} : X \mapsto \sum_{n \in X} n\:$ *order preserving*  from $(P(\{1,2\},\subseteq)$ to  $(\mathbb{N}, \le)$ - and also injective.

1.) Is there injective, *order preserving*  map from $(\mathbb{N},\le)$ to $(\mathbb{N}, | )$??

2.)Is there injective, *order preserving* map from  $(\mathbb{N_+}, | )$ to $(\mathbb{N},\le)$?

Answer (score 1):

For 1:
$$
\phi(n) = 2^n
$$

For 2: 
$$
\phi(n)=n.
$$

Comment: Thx you Emanuele...Could you give me a rough explanation to understand your approach..THX a lot